# Does anyone know where I can watch a good quality of Magi Adventures of Sinbad English dub

Tags: magi

I have been trying to look for it but they are all bad quality and have too may add or are not English.

Comment: How have you found _any_ that are in English? The Adventures of Sinbad OVAs haven't been dubbed.

Answer (score 2):

We have a list of [Legal Streaming Sources here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/923/1587). considering that Aniplex licensed Magi for the states their streaming channel has [Season 1](http://aniplexchannel.com/show-page/magi) and [Season 2](http://aniplexchannel.com/show-page/magi-2), assume that the Magi you have tagged is the same as the one you mention in the title. (as Season 1 is called *Magi: The Labyrinth of Magic* and Season is is called *Magi: The Kingdom of Magic*)

I am unable to confirm whether or not these episodes are dubbed in English as Geo-blocking prevents non US users from viewing the videos (i am in Australia), however considering [DVD Set 1](http://www.rightstufanime.com/Magi-The-Labyrinth-of-Magic-DVD-Set-1-Hyb) has English listed as a spoken language and it's publishing is listed as Aniplex of America i would suspect that the episodes on their streaming channel are English Dub

EDIT: Thanks to [senshin's comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/31435/does-anyone-know-where-i-can-watch-a-good-quality-of-magi-adventures-of-sinbad-e/31438?noredirect=1#comment43780_31438) i have come to realize that the series and Aniplex of America has aren't what you are looking for. looking on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magi:_The_Labyrinth_of_Magic) and [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=16497) neither lists any english distributors/companies/licencees for the either the 2014 OVA or the current *Adventure of Sinbad* [anime adaptation](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=17687) of the manga of the same name. this leads me to suspect that it is not officially released outside Japan at this time (17/04/2016) so i would suspect a dub for these does not exist.

That being said generally when a company like Funimation or Aniplex gets the licenses to stream/distribute a series there is a high chance that they will also get any new season (though there are some exceptions). so at this time it's probably best to keep an eye on Aniplex of America for if/when they post up the dubs for the series your looking for. checking the other sites in the list i posted wont hurt either just incase

Comment: "Magi: Adventures of Sinbad" is a different thing (a side story) from "Magi: The Labyrinth of Magic" and "Magi: The Kingdom of Magic".